# How to Display emojis in PDFs generated by FOP Apache

Tags: pdf, emoji, apache-fop

I am looking for a way to display as many characters (including emojis) as possible in PDFs generated by FOP Apache. The FOP people advise to use a font containing the emojis, but I tried NotoColorEmoji.ttf from Google and got an exception. I have also tried Symbola etc. but all fonts seem to be old and emojis separated by a a ZWJ (zero width joiner) don't work. I also tried Curier New, since it displays emojis correctly in Windows 10, but the ttf, does not contain emojis. The characters I need to display are as follows:

ÄÖÜ

个相同基因的更多拷⻉来提⾼适应性

Πρωτότυπο κβαντικό ραντάρ από ερευνητές στην Αυστρία

☹️☺️

‍⚕️

The Exception when using NotoColorEmoji.ttf is as follows:

```
2021-01-27 15:19:18,104 ERROR Failed to read font file file:///C:/Roboto/Noto/NotoColorEmoji.ttf 'loca' table not found, happens when the font file doesn't contain TrueType outlines (trying to read an OpenType CFF font maybe?): java.io.IOException: 'loca' table not found, happens when the font file doesn't contain TrueType outlines (trying to read an OpenType CFF font maybe?)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll likely need a few fonts to capture all of those characters.
You could try including some of these in your list of font families (your ordering may need some tweaking depending on your preferences of what is used first if it has the glyphs). My "go to" list is for both Mac and Windows, and captures more than what is in your sample, but I think it should handle it.

```
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
         xmlns:fox="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions"
         font-family="Segoe UI, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Segoe UI Emoji, Symbola, Arial, Ping Fang HK, Ping Fang SC, Ping Fang TC, Heiti SC, Heiti TC, Beijing, Taipei, Malgun Gothic, Batang, Gungsuh, Microsoft JhenHei, Microsoft YaHei, Aparajita, Kokila, Mangal, Nirmala UI, Sanskrit Text, Utsaah, Tahoma, Arial Unicode MS, Apple SD Gothic Neo, AppleGothic, sans-serif">
```